# LINK : fatal error LNK1146: no argument specified with option '/MT'

Tags: c, compiler-errors, windows-xp, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and trying to compile a program that was compatible with Windows XP 32-bit.

When I first ran my .exe on my VM it said that it wasn't compatible with Win32.
I've then changed the Platform Toolset to Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_xp).
Now it says I'm missing a VCRUNTIME140d.dll, and following instructions that said to change my Runtime Library to /MT I get the error stated in the title.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `/MT` is a compiler, not a linker option. Simply build your project in Release mode and install the necessary redistributable for XP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VCRUNTIME140d.dll is [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145).You need to download and install. And this is Debug versions of DLL. You must compile in Release mode.